# scroll a collection of divs inside a main div

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a group of small div boxes that go horizontally along the top of my page , There could be up to 50 of these that I want to display as scrollable inside an existing larger div . I had set the main 'FloatMain' div to overflow:scroll and I though this would be the answer but the small divs just keep over flowing the main div. I have looked at all the solutions on here but nothing seems to help me with me particular problem, Any help please ?

```
  <div id="FloatMain">

  <div title="Driver Details" id="i1001" class="divd" style="left:100px">i1001<br>Paul Stott</div>
  <div title="Driver Details" id="i1002" class="divd" style="left:155px">i1002<br>Simon Latcham</div>
  <div title="Driver Details" id="i1003" class="divd" style="left:210px">i1003<br>Phil Murphy</div>
  <div title="Driver Details" id="i1004" class="divd" style="left:265px">i1004<br>Lee Taylor </div>
  <div title="Driver Details" id="i1005" class="divd" style="left:320px">i1005<br>Martin Macklin</div>
  <div title="Driver Details" id="i1006" class="divd" style="left:375px">i1006<br></div>
  etc ... more of these .....

  </div>
```

The style details

```
.divd {
position:fixed ;
width: 50px;
height: 50px;   
top: 50px ;
left: 50px ; 
border: 1px solid black;
background-color:#999; 
border-radius:5px;  
z-index:200;
}

#FloatMain {
position:fixed ; 
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
top: 40px ; 
border: 2px solid black;
background-color:#FFF;
color:#000;  
left:50% ; 
margin-left:-150px;
display:none ;
border-radius:7px;  
z-index:10;
}
```

Comment: could you post an example of such page?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `divd` divs have `position:fixed`. I don't think you can achieve what you want with that.

I would insert an extra container div with `position:relative`, and then put all your `divd` divs inside that with `position:absolute`. Or, better yet, just make all your `divd` divs `float:left` and then you can remove all those `style` attributes in your HTML.

Here's a jsfiddle example for the latter approach: http://jsfiddle.net/4EUVE/1/

Comment: Thanks for your time, The extra container did the trick !, many thanks

Answer (score 1):

you can use like this:

```
 .divd {
    width: 50px;
    height: 50px;   
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color:#999; 
    border-radius:5px;  
    }

    #FloatMain {
     background-color: #FFFFFF;
        border: 2px solid black;
        border-radius: 7px 7px 7px 7px;
        color: #000000;
        height: 300px;
        width: 300px;
        overflow-y:scroll;
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for looking at this !, This is close to what I want to do , but all the small divs cascade diagonally from each other, What I need to do is keep them all in a row at the top of the page  (ie top:50px)

Answer (score 0):

Keep the overflow property as you added before and add

`<div style="clear:both"/>` before ending parent div. hope it would work.